# Convert TResult to Func<TResult> in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, func

I have a method that returns an image as a `System.IO.Stream`, and I need to convert it to a `System.Func<System.IO.Stream>` instead.

```
Stream stream2 = RaiseContrast(bitmap); 
Photo.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(stream2);
```

The above code doesn't work because `FromStream` requires a `Func<Stream>`.

How do I convert `stream2` into a `Func<Stream>` so I can display the image with `FromStream`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a lambda expression: `() =>` . The call will be:

```
Photo.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream2);
```

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: This works, but if you don't mind me asking, does the lamba expression just make it a method that returns stream2 instead of just stream2 by itself?

Comment: It makes an anonymous method indeed.